# Open API for spring gateway without service discovery

Tags: java, microservices, openapi, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to integrate Open api to my gateway so that I can access all the swagger documentation of employee-service through the gateway. I have not used any service discovery

In gateway micro service , I have added

```
  <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
           <version>2021.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
           <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
           <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.31</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have added the routes of employee service in the application.yaml of gateway service .I am  able to access the api's of employee service from the gateway. ,

```
  spring:
          cloud:
            gateway:
              routes:
              - id: employee-service
                uri: http://localhost:8082
                predicates:
                - Path=/employee/**
```

In gateway, I have also configured

```
@Autowired
RouteDefinitionLocator locator;

@Bean
public List<GroupedOpenApi> apis() {
   List<GroupedOpenApi> groups = new ArrayList<>();
   List<RouteDefinition> definitions = locator.getRouteDefinitions().collectList().block();
   definitions.stream().filter(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId().matches(".*-service")).forEach(routeDefinition -> {
      String name = routeDefinition.getId().replaceAll("-service", "");
      GroupedOpenApi.builder().pathsToMatch("/" + name + "/**").setGroup(name).build();
   });
   return groups;
}
```

But the open api integration is not working. I see many instances of local host running . I have attached the image of the logs in the gateway service .

[image: gateway logs]
Can some one tell me how to fix this.